# Can't specify Qt version macOS and can't find Kit

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I am trying to install Qt Creator properly on MacOS 12.2.1 (Macbook Air M1)

My actions:

1. brew install qt
2. Downloaded qt-unified-macOS-x64-4.6.1-online.dmg from this page https://www.qt.io/download-open-source
3. On the "Select components" installation stage I see only "Qt insights Tracker TP" option (see picture)

[image]

but I expected something like Qt 6.6 for desktop development instead of "Qt insights Tracker TP"

After the installation I am trying to create a new Qt console application and I don't see available Kit

[image]

My QT version seems fine:
[image]

Comment: Can you try running the installer using the mirror `--mirror http://qt.mirror.constant.com`?

Answer (score 0):

It's some kind of a bug on their side. I had the same issue. Just tried again on the next day and it worked fine.